# Referencing a workspace project from Tycho build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

Recently I successfully set up a Tycho environment for building my RCP application and it works fine. But I have one problem - my project referencing another project with library, which is not an eclipse plugin, and when I add this project to classpath of my RCP plugin, Tycho fails to compile it complaining the library classes is not found, so I have co copy jar with this library to plugin's folder. This is not comfortable, as I cannot directly debug and modify the library, and I need to copy jar each time I modify it, and for some reason eclipse opens and does not close this jar after a debug run, so I need to restart eclipse to copy it.

Obviously, there should be a way to instruct Tycho to resolve workspace dependencies, but I cannot find any clues in internet.

So can anyone help?

Here is how the workspace tree look:

```
com.portlab.jc2.client
-bundles
--com.portlab.jc2.client.rcp
---src
----....
---icons
----....
---META-INF
----MANIFEST.MF
---Application.e4xmi
---build.properties
---plugin.xml
---JC2-engine-1.0.0.jar
---.... (jars required by JC2-engine)
-features
--com.portlab.jc2.client.feature
---....
-releng
--....
-pom.xml

JC2-engine
-....
```

The problem localized as:

The main tycho project contains RPC bundle, which is requiring purejavacomm via maven dependency.
It also require a libray, which is also used in several other projects (not eclipse-based), and this library require purejavacomm also.
Tycho 2.2 allows resolving of maven dependencies, and as I reference engine library, it is automatically tryes to resolve purejevacomm too. So I cannot add it as a dependency to my RCP project, as it is already referenced by engine.
But in eclipse I see warnings on all references to purejavacomm objects about access restriction: not an API.
After that the application cannot start from eclipse, complaining about one of purejavacomm classes not found, and maven build is also fails with compilation errors on purejavacomm classes referenced from rcp project.

I found some wird workaround to make maven build to be succesful: adding a wrapper for purejavacomm to feature dependencies and also to MANIFEST.MF (which immediately produces error in eclipse), but after build arifact does not run with error loading classes for another maven library referenced by engine - Jackson.

Eclipse Run/Debug session fails to start anyway.

Comment: Why is JC2-engine a JAR instead of a plugin/bundle? In case it's because JC2-engine is a Maven project with non-plugin dependencies, see the new [Maven target locations support feature of Tycho 2.2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/2.2#Support_for_m2e_PDE_Maven_target_locations). Alternatively, the JARs can also be created and copied automatically within the Maven-Tycho build (e.g. via Ant script in the `pom.xml`).

Comment: A plugin can also be used as library/dependency in a plain Java project. Does it contain native code for ARM 32-bit? But in any case, what's the problem with that? I don't see the limitation that you see here preventing to create a separate plugin. Yes, a JAR inside of a plugin should be avoided. Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That sound like in your Tycho build `pom.xml` `com.portlab.test.engine` is missing as module before the `com.portlab.test.client.rcp` module. But it's hard to help without having an example.

Comment: I've been successfully build test project, but for production project I still have problems: the engine project requires some libraries, like purejavacomm and jackson, and this libs are set up as maven dependencies. But the main project cannot resolve them, not as if it ran from eclipse, nor in a zip package produced by tycho build.

Comment: Since Tycho 2.2 you can also have Maven dependencies in your plugin: https://läubisoft.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/

Comment: Yes, I did exactly like this, but I cannot run it now, gettin an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: purejavacomm/PortInUseException`, and tycho cannot build it: `[ERROR] G:\Git\com.portlab.jc2.client\com.portlab.jc2.client\bundles\com.portlab.jc2.client.rcp\src\com\portlab\jc2\client\rcp\ConnectDialog.java:[28] 
[ERROR]  import purejavacomm.CommPortIdentifier;`

Comment: Note, Tycho creates a wrapper for purejavacom: `[INFO] org.bidib.com.github.purejavacomm:purejavacomm:1.0.3.1 is wrapped as a bundle with bundle symbolic name wrapped.org.bidib.com.github.purejavacomm.purejavacomm
[INFO] The artifact can be referenced in feature files with the following data: <plugin id="wrapped.org.bidib.com.github.purejavacomm.purejavacomm" version=" 1.0.3.1" download-size="0" install-size="0" unpack="false"/>`

Comment: One more point - if I add wrapped.org.bidib.com.github.purejavacomm.purejavacomm to MANIFEST.MF file, tycho build is successful, but when I try to run an application I got an error with Jackson class loading. Jackson is required by engine too.